# Rails - session request is nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method that I want to execute some search logic, and then save a Search object that has the searched string and user id of the person who did the search.

The search/save logic seems to be working fine otherwise, but when I try to get the current user (using a method from the application controller) it throws a runtime error that has to do with the session:

```
ActionController::Metal#session delegated to @_request.session, but @_request is nil: #<SearchController:0x1038e32e0 @action_has_layout=true, @view_context_class=nil, @_status=200, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}>
```

Here's the method in the search controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

...

def factualsearch(search)

    if search

        searchquery = Search.new

        # this causes the error
        if current_user
        searchquery.user = current_user
        end

        searchquery.search_string = search

        searchquery.save

        ...

    end

    @results

end
```

end

Here's the current_user method I'm trying to call from my application controller:

```
def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end

helper_method :current_user
```

Here's the pages controller where I'm calling the method:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

...

def search

    searchcontrol = SearchController.new        

    @results = searchcontrol.factualsearch(params[:search])

end

...
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a direct way to fix this problem, but I was able to get around it by have the function accept the user in addition to the search query, rather than trying to call the current_user method from inside it.  The class that calls the action can access the current_user method just fine.